# FOR XML EXPLICIT: Create multiple result rows

Tags: sql-server, for-xml-explicit

I want to create multiple XML Files/Result Rows in one statement.

What I have:

```
with invoices as (
    select '1' HID, 'Test1' HData, '1' PID, 'Pos1' PData union
    select '1' HID, 'Test1' HData, '2' PID, 'Pos2' PData union
    select '1' HID, 'Test1' HData, '3' PID, 'Pos3' PData union
    select '2' HID, 'Test2' HData, '4' PID, 'Pos1' PData union
    select '2' HID, 'Test2' HData, '5' PID, 'Pos2' PData union
    select '2' HID, 'Test2' HData, '6' PID, 'Pos3' PData
)
select
    case when GROUPING_ID(PID) = 0 then 4
        when GROUPING_ID(HData) = 0 then 3
        when GROUPING_ID(HID) = 0 then 2
        else 1 end tag,
    case when GROUPING_ID(PID) = 0 then 2
        when GROUPING_ID(HData) = 0 then 2
        when GROUPING_ID(HID) = 0 then 1
        else null end parent,
    null [Root!1],
    HID [Invoice!2!HID],
    HData [Header!3!HData!Element],
    PID [Pos!4!PID],
    PData [Pos!4!PData!Element]
from invoices
group by grouping sets ((), (HID), (HID, HData), (HID, HData, PID, PData))
order by HID, HData, PID
for xml explicit, type;
```

What I get:
[image: get]

What I want:
[image: want]

Is this possible? How would one do that?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to generate the `XML` output for each distinct `HID`:

```
;WITH invoices as (
    select '1' HID, 'Test1' HData, '1' PID, 'Pos1' PData union
    select '1' HID, 'Test1' HData, '2' PID, 'Pos2' PData union
    select '1' HID, 'Test1' HData, '3' PID, 'Pos3' PData union
    select '2' HID, 'Test2' HData, '4' PID, 'Pos1' PData union
    select '2' HID, 'Test2' HData, '5' PID, 'Pos2' PData union
    select '2' HID, 'Test2' HData, '6' PID, 'Pos3' PData
)
SELECT 
   XMLColumn = (
      select
         case when GROUPING_ID(PID) = 0 then 4
              when GROUPING_ID(HData) = 0 then 3
              when GROUPING_ID(HID) = 0 then 2
              else 1 
         end tag,
         case when GROUPING_ID(PID) = 0 then 2
              when GROUPING_ID(HData) = 0 then 2
              when GROUPING_ID(HID) = 0 then 1
              else null 
         end parent,
         null [Root!1],
         HID [Invoice!2!HID],
         HData [Header!3!HData!Element],
         PID [Pos!4!PID],
         PData [Pos!4!PData!Element]
      from invoices
      WHERE i.HID = HID
      group by grouping sets ((), (HID), (HID, HData), (HID, HData, PID, PData))
      order by HID, HData, PID
      for xml explicit, type
   )
FROM invoices i
GROUP BY HID
```